# This is a bug in Flink-1.13.1 & HiveCatalog

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Flink:1.13.1

Hive:2.1.1—cdh6.2.1

The jar packages in the flink/lib directory are shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdu7s.png)
When I execute sql-client.sh, I get the following error, which requires me to submit comments to the Apache Flink community.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClientException: Unexpected exception. This is a bug. Please consider filing an issue.
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:201)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:161)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.catalog.exceptions.CatalogException: A database with name [hive] does not exist in the catalog: [myhive].
        at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.setCurrentDatabase(CatalogManager.java:295)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.useDatabase(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1450)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.initializeCatalogs(LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.java:202)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.initializeSessionState(LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.java:105)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.SessionContext.create(SessionContext.java:233)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalContextUtils.buildSessionContext(LocalContextUtils.java:100)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.openSession(LocalExecutor.java:91)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:187)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a forum to ask questions - not to report bugs. If you believe you found a bug, report it to the Apache Link community directly. If you are not sure, then it might be more helpful if you rephrase your post as a question, showing an example/sample of your own code, as well as a brief summary of the generated error.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed together libraries compiled for different (and incompatible) versions of scala. That's not going to work. Pick either 2.11 or 2.12 and use it consistently.

Comment: I replaced it with the unified Scala 2.12, still reporting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in flink that we are continuously facing while, we were trying to open the ./sql-client.sh on pyflink Can anyone address this issue. Which requires me to submit comments to the Apache Flink community.
Even I was having only the single version of scala 2.12 within the lib folder of pyflink but it is still giving the below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdM3O.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.